# Clearing filters in a grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am working on clearing filters in the grid.

`grid.filters.clearFilters()` will clear the filters on page refresh i.e it will uncheck the checkbox and all the records are displayed but the text in the textbox is not cleared

How can i clear the texbox value when i hit page refresh.

Comment: http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-46351.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this when grid's render event is fired:

```
Ext.getCmp('my_textbox_id').reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to clear your textbox check. Just search google on how to do this.

[Check and uncheck checkboxes in Javascript](http://www.shiningstar.net/articles/articles/javascript/checkboxes.asp)